# Как записать данные в родительский параметр объекта

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, lodash

Столкнулся с проблемой с тем, что нужно обработать сложный формат данных и результат выполнения функции записать в родительский параметр.

К примеру

```
parse({
  email: { __value__: 'mailingList[0].email' }
}, {mailingList: [{ email: 'email@x.com' }]}) 
// на выходе должно получиться { email: 'email@x.com' }
```

На данный момент у меня не получается записать в родителя (email). Вот как у меня выходит

```
{email: { __value__: 'email@x.com' }}
```

И нужно реализовать пример со сложной структурой

```
parse({
  user: {
    email: {
      __value__: 'mailingList[0].email',
    },
    password: {
      __random__: {
        minLength: {
          __value__: 'minPasswordLength',
        },
        maxLength: {
          __value__: 'maxPasswordLength',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}, // что необходимо обработать
{
  mailingList: [{ email: 'email@x.com' }],
  minPasswordLength: 6,
  maxPasswordLength: 24,
} // полезная нагрузка
)
```

Что должно получиться на выходе:

```
{email: 'email@x.com', password: 'randomstring'}
```

> __value__, __random__, и т.п. - это js функции, в которые можно передавать в качестве параметров: 1. объект, число, строку, массив , 2. это данные ( полезная нагрузка ).

К примеру **value**, принимает строку, путь к объекту полезной нагрузки (data).

```
__value__('mailingList[0].email',{mailingList: [{ email: 'email@x.com' }]}) // => email@x.com
```

Мой код

```
const methods: Map<string, Function> = new Map<string, Function>()
methods.set('__value__', __value__)
function parse(obj: Input, data: object): Input {
  if (_.isObject(obj)) {
    _.mapKeys(obj, (val, key) => {
      const fn = methods.get(key)
      if (fn) {
        obj[key] = fn(val, data)
      }
    })
  }

  return obj
}

function __value__(obj: Input, data: object): Input {
  if (Array.isArray(obj) || typeof obj === 'string') {
    return _.get(data, obj, obj)
  }
  return build(obj, data)
}
```

Comment: Предоставьте изначальный объект и конечный формат.

Comment: Обновил задание

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `key` должен быть `__value__`

см. `TODO` в коде

```js
const log = (...q) => console.log('debug:', ...q)


const methods = new Map()

methods.set('__value__', __value__)
function __value__(obj, data) {
    if (_.isArray(obj) || typeof obj === 'string') {
        return _.get(data, obj, obj)
    }
    return build(obj, data)
}

function parse(obj, data) {
    if (_.isObject(obj)) {
        _.mapKeys(obj, (val, key) => {
            // TODO: тут необхожимо пройтись по ещё одному уровню вложенности
            // `key` должен быть `__value__`
            log({ key })
            const fn = methods.get(key)
            if (fn) {
                obj[key] = fn(val, data)
            }
            // решение
            else if(_.isObject(obj[key])) {
                obj[key] = parse(obj[key], data)
            }
        })
    }
    return obj
}

const res = parse(
    {
        email: { __value__: 'mailingList[0].email' }
    },
    {
        mailingList: [{ email: 'email@x.com' }]
    }
)
log({ res })
```

```html
<script src="http://unpkg.com/lodash"></script>
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь! Я потратил на реализацию много времени, и был удивлен, когда мое решение совпало с вашим ( в плане подхода и алгоритма ) . Ставлю + за уделенное время моей задаче

Comment: Это не моё решение, это ваш код, с моим комментарием где ошибка. А ещё, заметил `Array.isArray` нужно/можно заменить на [_.isArray](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isArray). Да, не забудьте установить `@types/lodash`.

Comment: отредактировал ответ см. `// решение` там осталось совсем немного допилить "под себя"

Comment: а в чем разница _.isArray и  Array.isArray? Что лучше использовать ? Аналогичный вопрос и про Object.keys() и _.keys()

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1085658/232932

Answer (score 0):

Вот мое решение ( Если кому будет интересно )

```
public compile(input?: Input): Input {
    let obj: Input = input || { ...this.root }
    if (obj != null && typeof obj === 'object') {
      const keys = _.keys(obj)
      if (keys.length === 1 && !Array.isArray(obj)) {
        const key = keys[0]
        const fn = this.fns.get(key)
        if (fn) {
          obj = this.compile(fn(obj[key]))
        } else {
          _.set(obj, key, this.compile(obj[key]))
        }
      } else {
        for (const key of keys) {
          _.set(obj, key, this.compile(_.get(obj, key)))
        }
      }
    }
    return obj
  }
```