# методы из библиотеки VS нативные JS

Tags: javascript, faq

Меня тут спросили в комментариях (речь про [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash))

> а в чем разница _.isArray и Array.isArray? Что лучше использовать ? Аналогичный вопрос и про Object.keys() и _.keys()

Решил оформить вопросом и дать ответ на него.
Призываю сообщество принять участие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Общие сведения

### Документация

```
|   | библиотека/язык         |    |      | доки                                                |
|---|-------------------------|----|------|-----------------------------------------------------|
| 0 | TypeScript              | TS |      | https://www.typescriptlang.org                      |
| 1 | JavaScript (Vanilla JS) | JS |      | https://developer.mozilla.org                       |
| 2 | jquery                  | JQ | `$`  | https://api.jquery.com                              |
| 3 | lodash                  |    | `_`  | https://lodash.com                                  |
| 4 | underscore              |    | `_`  | https://underscorejs.org или http://underscorejs.ru |
| 5 | backbone                |    | `_`  | https://backbonejs.org или http://backbonejs.ru     |
| 5 | d3                      | d3 | `d3` | https://d3js.org                                    |
```

### Метки

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash) [underscore.js](/questions/tagged/underscore.js) [backbone.js](/questions/tagged/backbone.js) [d3.js](/questions/tagged/d3.js)

Вопросы по этим меткам [ru.stackoverflow.com/questions](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+or+jquery+or+lodash+or+underscore.js+or+backbone.js+or+d3.js)
Для тех кому мало примеров из документации.

## IMHO:

Здесь будет описана моя точка зрения.
Хотя возможно, её кто-либо захочет дополнить отредактировав этот ответ.

В тексте ниже, под библиотекой, подразумевается одна из библиотек из списка выше.

### В общем случае, кратко.

Если используется библиотека то необходимо использовать метод из библиотеки.

### В частном - за библиотеку.

#### вас попросили "немного подправить код"

Вас попросили "немного подправить код" и вы видите что код написан на JQ - однозначно используйте методы JQ!

#### разные версии JS

JS имеет много версий, некоторые вещи были добавлены недавно(относительно) - ES6+(es2015+).
Например `forEach` в JS не было, соответственно был момент когда есть браузер:

- с поддержкой
- и без поддержки.

**И в этом случае - код, написанный на JQ, работал везде.**

#### библиотека или язык программирования

Я предлагаю рассматривать библиотеки как отдельный язык.

Нет, я это сейчас серьёзно, ведь иной раз код на каком-нибудь JQ по виду отличается от JS больше чем TS.

#### на примере lodash

Возьмём мной уже упомянутый `forEach`. В lodash так же есть метод `forEachRight`, а в JS его нет.

- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEach
- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#forEachRight

А ещё в lodash есть такая штука как `_.chain()` и если вы привыкните чейнить,
то у вас и не будет вопроса использовать `forEach` из JS или библиотеки.

- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chain

```
var users = [
  { 'user': 'barney',  'age': 36 },
  { 'user': 'fred',    'age': 40 },
  { 'user': 'pebbles', 'age': 1 }
];

var youngest = _
  .chain(users)
  .sortBy('age')
  .map(function(o) {
    return o.user + ' is ' + o.age;
  })
  .head()
  .value();
// => 'pebbles is 1'
```

lodash на других я.п.:

- pydash - python
- lodash-php - php
- lodash.net - С#
- Rodash - Ruby
- go-dash - GO

Это небольшой списочек, первое что гугл выдал ...

#### на примере JQ

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "div" ).each(function( index, element ) {
    // element == this
    $( element ).css( "backgroundColor", "yellow" );
    if ( $( this ).is( "#stop" ) ) {
      $( "span" ).text( "Stopped at div index #" + index );
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

#### на примере underscorejs

заметка про underscorejs

> Кроме того, Underscore умеет делегировать вызовы, т.е. если код выполняется в современном браузере, который имеет нативные реализации таких методов, как: forEach, map, reduce, filter, every, some и indexOf, то будут вызваны именно они.

#### на примере backbonejs

-,-

#### на примере d3

```
d3.selectAll("p").style("color", "blue");
```

думаю всем понятно что происходит в коде сверху, как и то, что это мжно релизовать с помощь JS JQ.

Перейдите по ссылке и воспользуйтесь поиском по странице, найдите 'each'.

- [https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/API-Reference-(русскоязычная-версия)](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/API-Reference-(%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%8F))

я вот не уверен что для `map.forEach` из d3 сработает нативный из JS `forEach`

...

### В частном - против библиотеки.

если это:

- человек или команда знающая JS
- а ещё лучше TS
- есть DevOps
- webpack, babel сборки и компиляция проекта
- в том числе компиляция проекта под конкретные браузер версию

Людям которые понимают что написано выше так же ясно что такое Полифил и "с чем его едят".
Они просто берут и пишут на ESNext иногда даже на tc39 в стадии 0.
При использовании сторонней библиотеки они помнят про Tree Shaking и видят разницу между
`import { array } from 'someLib'` и `import array from 'someLib/array'` и берут от библиотеки ровно столько, сколько им нужно.

Comment: А если разработка идет под серверные приложения на Node.js, тут важна производительность ( даже в наносекундах ), что тогда лучше использовать ? Могли бы вы дать конкретные цифры, графики, объективное сравнение .

Comment: --  Почему замеры - дело не простое: у меня ноут 4 ядра 8 потоков + турбобуст + тротлинг, понижайка при нагреве(защита). То есть частота плавает ... .  --   https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/890754/232932, http://underscorejs.ru/test.  --  Про тот же `forEach` по началу говорили чётко и ясно - он медленнее перебора через `for`.  --  Наносекунды это конечно хорошо, но ещё лучше работающий, правильно работающий код, согласитесь : ) дешевле "купить ещё один сервер" чем нанять вторую команду для поиска ошибок.  --  там же где действительно важны наносекунды - скорее всего используют другой язык.

Comment: Если скрипт используется в серверных веб приложениях, важны и наносекунды. И использовать другой язык - не вариант. Да и зачем эти отговорки. Вопрос же ясный и четкий , что лучше.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_c_addons

Comment: Да, я знаю про модули на c++, но мне сейчас важнее получить ответ на вопрос, что лучше использовать в плане производительности:  Object.keys или _.keys()

Comment: если вам что-то действительно очень важно знать - оформите вопросом, если вы хотите чтобы я его прокомментировал - поделитесь ссылкой.

Comment: вон [там](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/890754/232932), я привёл тесты и результаты на три Нативных метода, это не библиотека, это чистый JS. разберитесь в них и напишите свой ...